# Memory Leak issue with my code, I am newbie

Tags: c++

I keep getting a Memory Leak which seems to occur because the new initialized objects passed as pointers to `add(…)` are not actually `delete`. But somehow, I cannot make this work properly. I tried adding a `for`-loop to loop every object in array within class Monsters to `delete` each object when the call of the `destructor` is invoked. And then to do `delete[] monsters;` and `monsters = nullptr`.

https://repl.it/@xxxxxx10/TatteredTroubledTasks

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Monster{
public:
  Monster(){};
  Monster(std::string name) : name(name){}
private:
  std::string name = "";
};

class MonstersList {
public:
  MonstersList(int max):max(max){
    monsters = new Monster[max];
  }
  
  virtual ~MonstersList() {
      delete[] monsters;
  }

  void add(const Monster* m){
    monsters[total++] = *m;
  }

 Monster* begin() const { return monsters; }
 Monster* end() const { return monsters + total; }

private:
  Monster* monsters = nullptr;
  int max = 0;
  int total = 0;
};

MonstersList* InitListOfMonsters()
{
    MonstersList* monsters = new MonstersList(2);
    monsters->add(new Monster("Sally"));
    monsters->add(new Monster("Rich"));
    
    return monsters;
}

int main()
{
  MonstersList* monsters = InitListOfMonsters();
  
  // Do something here...

  return 0;
} // <----- Memory leak!
```

How can this be prevented from happening, recall, I tried to for loop and delete each monster pointer object in the array.

**EDIT:** When I try for-loop to delete each object, then an error sort of occurs, breaks at `delete_scalar.cpp` <-- Microsoft C++ file.

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

Occurs when I run this code in `destructor`:

```
if (monsters != nullptr) {
    for (Monster* m = begin(); m != end(); m++) {
        delete m;
    }

    delete[] monsters;
    monsters = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Monsters> monsters = InitListOfMonsters();`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I know about `std::unique_ptr<Monster>`, but, I am doing this the old school way.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, I been Googling and trying things out for days. It does compile in my Visual Studio.

Comment: `MonsterList` != `Monsters` != `Monster`, if this code really compiles in Visual Studio (I don't have it available to test), then you should use a more reliable tool.

Comment: @AlbinM *but, I am doing this the old school way.* -- The "old school" way requires you to know about user-defined copy constructors, assignment operators, etc.  Just using `new[]` and `delete[]` teaches very little.  To actually fix your classes, it requires much more effort than you've led to believe.

Comment: Your `add` function calls already leaks memory, as you pass in a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, copy the pointed to object and then discard the pointer, never freeing the memory it referred to

Comment: @UnholySheep, I didn't know that.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, I updated the entire code here.

Comment: And your loop with `delete m;` is also completely flawed, as you have an array of `Monster`, not of `Monster*` - you cannot call `delete` on the objects stored in the array

Comment: @UnholySheep, I thought I could loop over every individual object and delete them.

Comment: @AlbinM -- *I thought I could loop over every individual object and delete them.* -- C++ is a complex language.  You can't learn it by trial and error, which seems to be how you're going about it.

Comment: You can only `delete` what you `new` - and the objects in your array have not been `new`d (since they aren't pointers to objects)

Comment: @UnholySheep, so my function for adding many objects is wrong?

Comment: Yes, your function is wrong. It's also unclear why you are trying to pass a pointer to `add` instead of a reference. Combined with all the other issues in your code you should see why the recommended way to write modern C++ code is to use `std::vector` and smart pointers instead of manually managing such memory (and generally avoiding writing `new` and `delete`).

Comment: @AlbinM It's at the point where an answer would more than likely be a total rewrite of what you're doing.  This isn't something that can be fixed with a tweak here or there. 
 Like I stated, to get your code to actually work and be usable, given you want to do things the "old school way", would require a lot more work than you had thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's my old school effort. See comments at various points in the code for the things you were missing.

References

[What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

[What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

It is good to know this stuff, although that doesn't mean you should be old school. Modern C++ is better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

class Monster
{
public:
    Monster() {};
    Monster(std::string name) : name(name) {}
private:
    std::string name = "";
};

class MonstersList
{
public:
    MonstersList(int max) : monsters(new Monster[max]), max(max), total(0)
    {
    }

    // copy constructor, essential if your destructor deletes, see rule of three
    MonstersList(const MonstersList& rhs) : monsters(new Monster[rhs.max]), max(rhs.max), total(rhs.total)
    {
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
    }

    // assignment operator, again essential with a deleting destructor, 
    // this implementation uses the copy and swap idiom
    MonstersList& operator=(MonstersList rhs)
    {
        swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~MonstersList()
    {
        delete[] monsters;
    }

    void swap(MonstersList& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(monsters, rhs.monsters);
        std::swap(max, rhs.max);
        std::swap(total, rhs.total);
    }

    void add(const Monster& m) // pass by reference
    {
        monsters[total++] = m;
    }

    Monster* begin() const { return monsters; }
    Monster* end() const { return monsters + total; }

private:
    Monster* monsters;
    int max;
    int total;
};

MonstersList* InitListOfMonsters()
{
    // allocate a list of monsters, but no need to allocate the monsters themselves
    MonstersList* monsters = new MonstersList(2);
    monsters->add(Monster("Sally"));
    monsters->add(Monster("Rich"));

    return monsters;
}

int main()
{
    MonstersList* monsters = InitListOfMonsters();
    // Do something here...

    // don't forget to delete the monster list
    delete monsters;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `monsters->add({"Sally"}); monsters->add({Rich"});` -- Looks a little nicer, IMO.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes looks good, I still have to get used to uniform initialisation

Comment: @john, this wouldn't work with Monster* m = new Monster("Sally"); and then monsters->add(m);

Comment: @AlbinM No it wouldn't, but there is no reason to allocate the Monsters objects when your MonsterList class stores Monsters not Monster pointers. So the code above is an improvement. If you want to allocate Monster objects as well then you need to change your MonsterList class to store Monster pointers.

Comment: @AlbinM -- As another comment suggested, it seems you have the misconception that C++ requires `new` to create objects.  This is not the case.

Comment: @AlbinM For example `Monster m("Sally");` and then `monsters->add(m);`

Answer (score 4):

There are two places, where the code leaks memory

```
MonstersList* InitListOfMonsters()
{
    // ...
    monsters->add(new Monster("Sally"));
    // ...
    
    return monsters;
}
```

Each of the `new`s alloctes memory, which is never freed. Since you don't store pointers, but `Monster` objects, you should not pass pointers, but `Monster`s.

```
monsters->add(Monster("Sally"));
```

and modify `add()` as

```
void add(Monster const &m) {
    monsters[total++] = m;
}
```

The second one I see, is in `main`

```
MonstersList* monsters = InitListOfMonsters();
```

there's no corresponding

```
delete monsters;
```

The destructor is not executed until the object is destroyed.
This happens, when you call `delete monsters`.

---

Update for the **EDIT**

This code has two issues

```
if (monsters != nullptr) {
    for (Monster* m = begin(); m != end(); m++) {
        delete m;
    }

    delete[] monsters;
    monsters = nullptr;
}
```

the loop is equivalent to

```
for (Monster* m = monsters; m != (monsters + total); m++) {
    delete m;
}
```

The first `delete` is `delete monsters`, which deletes the whole array and causes a double delete with the later `delete[] monsters`.
Furthermore does it delete the following elements, which are not allocated separately, but as part of the whole array (which was already deleted in the first iteration).

The second issue is [`delete` vs `delete[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete). A simple `delete` is for *single objects*, whereas `delete[]` is for dynamically allocated *arrays*. In this case the first `delete m` inside for deletes an array with the non-array delete.

---

Finally, heed the suggestions and warnings in the comments.
When you use C++, especially C++11 and newer, do it the C++ way. Use `vector` and `unique_ptr`, if pointers are really necessary.

Comment: *there's no corresponding* that's because I am expecting the **destructor** to be executed. That's why.

Comment: There's no destructor for a pointer. See updated answer.

Comment: Olaf, what if `Monster* m = new Monster("Sally");` and then `monsters->add(m);` would this still be valid, even if `add` takes a reference?

Comment: @AlbinM Destructors are not  automatic with naked dynamic allocation. Automatic destruction of dynamic allocation requires an automatic watchdog (i.e. *smart pointers* which, if you must use dynamic allocation, should be mandatory, but only after you've determine you even need manual dynamic allocation in the first place, and chances are even-keel whether you do or don't).

Comment: @AlbinM You seem to come from other languages where `new` is frequently used or even required to create objects. However that's not the case in C++. In modern C++ you almost never need to (or should) use a naked `new` or naked pointers. Especially when you are new to C++ I'd recommend to _not_ use raw pointers, but to stick with smart pointers and standard containers.